# Checking the status of a process using its PID from Python

Tags: python, rest, flask, pid, flask-restful

My REST API written in Python spawns processes that take about 3 minutes to complete. I store the PID in a global array and setup a secondary check method that should confirm whether the process is still running, or if it has finished.

The only methods I can find are to poll the subprocess (which I don't have access to in this route), or try to kill the process to see if it's alive. Is there any clean way to just get a binary answer of if it's still running based on the PID, and if it completed successfully if not?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Response
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

QUEUE_ID = 0

jobs = []

@app.route("/compile", methods=["POST"])
def compileFirmware():

    f = request.files['file']
    f.save(f.filename)

    os.chdir("/opt/src/2.0.x")

    process = Popen(['platformio', 'run', '-e', 'mega2560'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

    global QUEUE_ID
    QUEUE_ID += 1

    data = {'id':QUEUE_ID, 'pid':process.pid}
    jobs.append(data)

    output, errors = process.communicate()
    print (output)
    print (errors)

    response = jsonify()
    response.status_code = 202 #accepted
    response.headers['location'] = '/queue/' + str(QUEUE_ID)
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response

@app.route("/queue/<id>", methods=["GET"])
def getStatus(id):

    #CHECK PID STATUS HERE

    content = {'download_url': 'download.com'}
    response = jsonify(content)
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)
```

Comment: Would you consider using mutliprocessing Pool? Or Flask-executor which uses concurrent library? You could use kill with signal 0 to check if it is alive. It is not clear from the question if you are already doing it.

Comment: @Luv I'm fairly new to Python so I am not entirely familiar with those options. Will definitely check them out in more detail, but I am open to using whatever works

Comment: if you stored the `Popen` response (`process`) instead of just the PID (`process.pid`) in your `data` dict then you could examine `process.returncode` to find out if the process is still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little simulation that works:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Response, abort
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

QUEUE = { }

@app.route("/compile", methods=["POST"])
def compileFirmware():
    process = Popen(['python','-c','"import time; time.sleep(300)"'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    QUEUE[str(process.pid)] = process # String because in GET the url param will be interpreted as str
    response = jsonify()
    response.status_code = 202 #accepted
    response.headers['location'] = '/queue/' + str(process.pid)
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response

@app.route("/queue/<id>", methods=["GET"])
def getStatus(id):
    process = QUEUE.get(id, None)
    if process is None:
        abort(404, description="Process not found")
    retcode = process.poll()
    if retcode is None:
        content = {'download_url': None, 'message': 'Process is still running.'}
    else:
        # QUEUE.pop(id) # Remove reference from QUEUE ?
        content = {'download_url': 'download.com', 'message': f'process has completed with retcode: {retcode}'}
    response = jsonify(content)
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)
```

There are further considerations you must think about if this application is going to be used as more than an individual project.

- We use QUEUE global variable to store the states of processes. But in a real project, the deployment via wsgi / gunicorn can have multiple workers with each worker having its own global variable. So for scaling up, consider using a redis / mq data store instead.
- Does the QUEUE ever need to be cleaned up? Should it be cleaned up? It has a disadvantage that if you clean it up after the value has been GET once, the next GET fetches 404. It is a design decision if the GET api must be idempotent(most likely yes).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a fantastic example to build on. I had no idea Python had a queue system but that's exactly what I needed. Just to ask however, documentation says  QUEUE.get() removes and returns an item from the queue. Is there any way to fetch the process by ID without removing the entry?

Comment: QUEUE.get does not remove the item, QUEUE.pop would remove. QUEUE is the name of a global variable of the buiitin python type Dict. Its a convention to use all caps for global vars. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries  Subprocesses do not end in the same order in which they are created, so use of unordered types like dict instead of ordered ones like lists makes more sense. Also easy to look up.